Remote Job Error in Dmol3: No $ in File or Path (Material studio)
I’m encountering an error in Dmol3 while running a TS Search job:
"You cannot run remote jobs for files with names containing $."
However, my file name and path do not contain any $ symbols:
C:\Users\1321087\Documents\Materials Studio Projects\ex131_Files\Documents\O.xtd
The job runs successfully for Energy calculations, but not for TS Search.
I’ve tried renaming the file and moving it to a simpler path like C:\MaterialStudio\O.xtd, but the issue persists.
What could be causing this error, and how can I resolve it?
